# Aliases for select statements in SQLite query

Tags: sqlite

Is there some way I can use an alias to avoid repeating the nested `select` statement in this query?

```
select distinct
  ingot_sales.date_time as date,
  ingot_sales.name as buyer,
  ingot_sales.metal as metal,
  (select price from ingot_list where ingot_sales.metal = ingot_list.metal) as unit_price,
  ingot_sales.quantity as quantity,
  (select price from ingot_list where ingot_sales.metal = ingot_list.metal) * quantity as total_price,
  ingot_sales.paid as paid
from ingot_sales, ingot_list;
```

I tried using `unit_price` in place of the second nested `select`, but kept getting repeated rows with different calculated values in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the tables so you don't need the correlated subqueries:

```
select distinct
  s.date_time as date,
  s.name as buyer,
  s.metal as metal,
  l.price as unit_price,
  s.quantity as quantity,
  l.price * s.quantity as total_price,
  s.paid as paid
from ingot_sales s left join ingot_list l
on s.metal = l.metal
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! And also showed me an important technique I'll no doubt be using again.

Comment: Here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-join/ you can find more about joins.